# .net Regular Expression involving html tags

Tags: .net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that detects whether or not a string is anything more than a bunch of HTML tags.

So, desired functionality is:

```
Input -> Output

"<html></html>" -> False

"<html>Hi</html>" -> True

"<a href='google.com'>Click Me</a>" -> True

"hello" -> True

"<bold><italics></bold></italics>" -> False

"" -> Don't care
```

Once upon a time I could have done this myself, but it's been too long.

Thanks in advance.

edit: I don't care if they are real HTML tags.  Lets call anything inside <>'s a tag.  Also don't care if a start tag matches up with an end tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `"<[^>]*>"` with the empty string, trim the result and check if there is anything left afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I used this method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I once used this to strip out html tags:

```
const string tagsPatterns = "\\s*<.*?>\\s*"; 
value = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value, tagsPatterns, " ");
```

I guess you can play with it a bit (this version wanted to keep white spaces), to get the string with no tags, and check if it isn't empty

**Update 1:** Here it goes :)

```
bool HasText(string value)
{
    const string tagsPatterns = "<.*?>"; 
    value = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value, tagsPatterns, "");
    return value.Trim() != "";
}
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(HasText("<html></html>"));
    Assert.IsTrue(HasText("<html>Hi</html>"));
    Assert.IsTrue(HasText("<a href='google.com'>Click Me</a>"));
    Assert.IsTrue(HasText("hello"));
    Assert.IsFalse(HasText("<bold><italics></bold></italics>"));
    Assert.IsFalse(HasText(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article written by Phil Haack about using a [regular express to match html](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx).

Also, if you want a simple line of code, consider loading the string into an XmlDocument. It would parse it so you'll know if you have valid xml or not.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question a bit.